# C++ COM Windows Sensor APIs - Lack of floating point precision

Tags: c#, c++, windows, com, sensors

I've been developing an application in C++ that interfaces with the Windows Sensor APIs through COM.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318953(v=vs.85).aspx

I am actually porting a C# application that I wrote before this that used the Windows Sensor APIs through the WinRT APIs.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.devices.sensors

The C# application used the Inclinometer sensor to retrieve Pitch, Roll, and Yaw values of the system as floating point values (float 32bit).
In C# I would create the Inclinometer sensor, set the report interval to the minimum allowed, and then get callback events through the InclinometerReadingChanged function.

Now in C++, I do roughly the same thing (but with COM). The COM interface gives you the option to change the report interval AND the sensitivity, whereas the C#/.NET/WinRT interface automatically sets the sensitivity based on the report interval setting, for you. I still get sensor values Pitch, Roll, and Yaw values as 32bit floats but the precision has been cut off at the first decimal place!

```
Created sensor manager.
Permission: 0
Created collection.
Got sensor count: 12
Got sensor (to test).
Supports event!
Min report interval: 15
Current Report interval: 50
Setting current report interval to minimum...
New Current Report interval: 15
Current Sensitivity: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
Setting Sensitivity...
New Current Sensitivity: 0.01, 0.01, 0.01
Sensor started!
State changed!
Reading: -0.6, 0.8, 54.8
Reading: 2.7, 2.9, 53.4
Reading: 4.2, 3.9, 52.2
Reading: 4.2, 2.9, 51.9
Reading: 3.3, 2.3, 51.8
Reading: 2.3, 1.9, 51.7
Reading: 1.5, 1.6, 51.6
Reading: 0.9, 1.3, 51.6
Reading: 0.5, 1.2, 51.5
Reading: 0.2, 1.1, 51.5
Reading: 0, 1, 51.5
Reading: -0.1, 0.9, 51.5
Reading: -0.2, 0.9, 51.5
Reading: -0.3, 0.9, 51.5
Reading: -0.4, 0.8, 51.5
Reading: -0.5, 0.8, 51.5
Reading: -0.5, 0.8, 51.5
Reading: -0.5, 0.8, 51.5
Reading: -0.5, 0.8, 51.5
Reading: -0.6, 0.8, 51.5
Reading: -0.6, 0.8, 51.5
Reading: -0.6, 0.8, 51.5
```

The C# application did not have this problem. The two apis (WinRT and Win32/COM) are theoretically getting their data from the same underlying system.

Could COM be the culprit of removing the floating point precision?
I looked around whether it's possible to set the precision of the sensors themselves but there are no settings for that. (I tried the Accuracy and Resolution properties with no luck).

**EDIT:**
I am using std::cout to print the values. I tested whether it was the print routine by printing a hardcoded float with more precision and it printed correctly. I also went into the debugger and looked at the value in there and they were in the format: #.#000000# (ex. -2.70000005).